# Stratonovich integral in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, wick-theorem

I'm reading a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4911) on Wick renormalization and there are a couple of things that are not that clear to me.

The paper ends with the following sentence:

> In Euclidean quantum field theory, the existence of interacting fields leads to the exponential integrability problem of $S_n(f)$ for some very special $f$ on some specific abstract Wiener space. The Wick renormalization method reduces the problem to exponential integrability problem of $I_n(f)$.

Where $S_n(f)$ is the Stratonovich integral while $I_n(f)$ is the Ito integral.

So I wanted to ask: why are we dealing with a Stratonovich integral? Moreover, why is it relevant the fact of obtaining an Ito integral from a Stratonovich one?